# How to add custom certificate to git client? (Ubuntu)

Tags: git, ubuntu, certificate, gitlab

How to add custom certificate to git client?

I have certificate and i want to clone some project from gitlub.

But I has an error:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://some.gitlub.url':
>   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Windows analog: `git config --global http."https://some.gitlub.url".sslCAInfo "work/gitlab.cer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure GIT to trust your certificate

`$> git config --global http."https://some.gitlub.url".sslCAInfo ~/git-certs/cert.pem`

It's recommended also to do:

```
$> git config --global --unset http.sslVerify
$> git config --global --list
```